# mongodb aggregate pipeline if else to execute one of the query

Tags: mongodb, if-statement, mongodb-query, conditional-statements, aggregation-framework

My objects looks like the following

```
{
    id: 1,
    a: "val7f",
    b: "online",
    c: "reg",
    d: "retd"
},
{
    id: 2,
    a: "val6f",
    b: "online",
    c: "reg",
    d: "new"
},
{
    id: 3,
    a: "val6f",
    b: "offline",
    c: "non-reg",
    d: "new"
}
```

I want to build a query in the following manner.

```
if (a=="val7f" && b=="offline" && c="reg") has objs > 1 return result Objs
else if(a=="val7f" && b=="offline" && c="reg") has objs > 1 return result objs
etc.
```

I built the following query but values displayed are from `else` query even if there are results for the if case:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
    { $redact: {
        $cond: {
            if: { 
                $and: [ 
                    { $eq: [ "a", "val7f" ] }, 
                    { $eq: [ "b", "offline" ] }, 
                    { $eq: [ "c", "reg" ] } 
                ] 
            },
            then: "$$DESCEND",
            else: {
                $cond: {
                    if: { 
                        $and: [ 
                            { $eq: [ "$a", "val6f"] }, 
                            { $eq: [ "b", "offline"] }, 
                            { $eq: [ "c", "reg"] } 
                        ] 
                    },
                    else: "$$PRUNE"
                }
            }
        }
    } }
]);
```

Summarised as follows

I've put condition as follows

```
if: { 
    $and: [ 
            { $eq: [ "a", "val7f" ] }, 
            { $eq: [ "b", "offline" ] }, 
            { $eq: [ "c", "reg" ] } 
        ] 
    }
```

if this has result say

```
{
    id: 6,
    a: "val7f",
    b: "online",
    c: "reg",
    d: "retd"
}
```

it should return the above document.
in case there are no document matching criteria

else case should execute

```
if: {
    $and: [ 
      { $eq: [ "$a", "val6f"] }, 
      { $eq: [ "b", "offline"] }, 
      { $eq: [ "c", "reg"] }
     ] 
    }
```

and if there is match for this say

```
{
    id: 11,
    a: "val6f",
    b: "offline",
    c: "reg",
    d: "new"
}
```

In my case, for the query built above I'm getting both the documents in the output shell.

Comment: Please format your post.

Comment: is it fine. or you expect more explanation?

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve? Your if else statements are not clear. What is your expected output?

Comment: plz look into summary to understand what I'm getting in the output. and expectation. I hope you understand now.@gzc, @dikesh